# Joblib.load Key Error:253

Tags: python, classification, naivebayes, joblib

I am saving a Naive Bayes classifier with `Joblib.dump`. Each time my machine is run, it loads the model with `joblib.load(filename)`. This was working for a while but I started getting this error:

```
File "test.py", line 92, in categorize
subclf = joblib.load('/home/elalo/ServiceNow/multinomial.pkl')
 File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 575, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 507, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/pickle.py", line 1038, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
KeyError: 253
```

I currently have `Scikit-learn (0.18.1), scipy (0.19.1)`.

I'm not really sure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Have you updated any library, mainly numpy, scipy or scikit-learn, or maybe python?

Comment: Yeah, all modules are up to date and I'm running python 3.4. I tried using `pickle.load` instead and I got an `unpickling error` .

Comment: What I meant is, from the time you dumped (pickled) the data into the file, is the environment still the same or has it changed? Because if its changed, it may have problem unpickling the data which was saved with older versions.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Nothing has been updated to my knowledge. I am just going to rebuild my model, I can do that fairly quickly. Thanks for your help.